# read html code made by arduino at android

Tags: android, html, arduino

I want to read `html` code of `arduino` web server.
I can make web server simply with from [example 4](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Wifi_Shield_V2.0/#example-6-wifi-shield-and-android-app). code is below.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "WiFly.h"

#define SSID      "yum2"
#define KEY       "yum000000"
// check your access point's security mode, mine was WPA20-PSK
// if yours is different you'll need to change the AUTH constant, see the file WiFly.h for avalable security codes
#define AUTH      WIFLY_AUTH_WPA2_PSK

int flag = 0;

// Pins' connection
// Arduino       WiFly
//  2    <---->    TX
//  3    <---->    RX

SoftwareSerial wiflyUart(2, 3); // create a WiFi shield serial object
WiFly wifly(&wiflyUart); // pass the wifi siheld serial object to the WiFly class

void setup()
{
  wiflyUart.begin(9600); // start wifi shield uart port
  Serial.begin(9600); // start the arduino serial port
  Serial.println("--------- WIFLY Webserver --------");

  // wait for initilization of wifly
  delay(1000);

  wifly.reset(); // reset the shield
  delay(1000);
  //set WiFly params

  wifly.sendCommand("set ip local 80\r"); // set the local comm port to 80
  delay(100);

  wifly.sendCommand("set comm remote 0\r"); // do not send a default string when a connection opens
  delay(100);

  wifly.sendCommand("set comm open *OPEN*\r"); // set the string that the wifi shield will output when a connection is opened
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Join " SSID );
  if (wifly.join(SSID, KEY, AUTH)) {
      Serial.println("OK");
  } else {
      Serial.println("Failed");
  }

  delay(5000);

  wifly.sendCommand("get ip\r");
  char c;

  while (wifly.receive((uint8_t *)&c, 1, 300) > 0) { // print the response from the get ip command
      Serial.print((char)c);
  }

  Serial.println("Web server ready");

}

void loop()
{

    if(wifly.available())
    { // the wifi shield has data available
        if(wiflyUart.find("*OPEN*")) // see if the data available is from an open connection by looking for the *OPEN* string
        {
            Serial.println("New Browser Request!");
            delay(1000); // delay enough time for the browser to complete sending its HTTP request string
            // send HTTP header
            wiflyUart.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            wiflyUart.println("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            wiflyUart.println("Content-Length: 244"); // length of HTML code
            wiflyUart.println("Connection: close");
            wiflyUart.println();

            // send webpage's HTML code
            wiflyUart.print("<html>");
            wiflyUart.print("<head>");
            wiflyUart.print("<title>My WiFI Shield Webpage</title>");
            wiflyUart.print("</head>");
            wiflyUart.print("<body>");
            wiflyUart.print("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
            wiflyUart.print("<h3>10 20 30 40 50</h3>");
            wiflyUart.print("<a href=\"http://yahoo.com\">Yahoo!</a> <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a>");
            wiflyUart.print("<br/><button>My Button</button>");
            wiflyUart.print("</body>");
            wiflyUart.print("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

the web server work well.

I wrote simple android code to read `html` is below.

```
package com.example.http;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv;
    String urlAddress = "192.168.0.10"; // doesn't show
   // String urlAddress = "http://www.kma.go.kr/weather/main.jsp#1159068000"; // work well
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadHtml();
            }
        });
    }

    void loadHtml() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
                    HttpURLConnection conn =
                            (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                        conn.setUseCaches(false);
                        if (conn.getResponseCode()
                                == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                            BufferedReader br
                                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                                    (conn.getInputStream()));
                            while (true) {
                                String line = br.readLine();
                                if (line == null) break;
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            br.close();
                        }
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }

                    Log.d("test", sb.toString());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(sb.toString());
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

It work very well with  `String urlAddress = "http://www.kma.go.kr/weather/main.jsp#1159068000";`
but it doesn't show when using 
`String urlAddress = "192.168.0.10";` instead of before one. 
the `192.168.0.10` is allocated ip of `arduino` from DHCP that i can check on serial monitor.

there is any way to read html from arduino web server??

Comment: are you sure the android device and the arduino are on the same network?

Comment: yes, it is sure. they are in same network.

Answer (score 0):

Your `urlAddress` isn't a URL, it's just an IP address. You should fully qualify the address with the protocol and the path you want to land on, for example:

```
String urlAddress = "http://192.168.0.10/";
```

I would expect you're getting a [MalformedURLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html).